# How do I make a global counter in WordPress that updates every second?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, wordpress, datetime

I have a WordPress website. In this website I added a HTML with JS to have a counter that increases by 1 unit every second like this:
[HTLM and JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHPJA.png)
Result:
[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqZz8.png)

The problem that I'm facing is to make this counter running always, but if I refresh, the counter resets to the initial value.

I tried creating a "counter" value on WP_options via phpMyAdmin. But i have no idea how to fetch this value and update it every second into the table to all users see the same value in the website.

Comment: If your counter starts at 1,000, and increments by 1 every second, then after 60 seconds it would be 1,000. You just need to define when `1,000` is set for, for instance make it (or assume it) is on May 30, 2023 at 3:00 PM (in some time zone). Then just calculate the number of seconds between "now" and that time, multiply by your increment and add to your base value.

Comment: Something vaguely like this: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/ZEqNNZz?editors=1111

Comment: @ChrisHaas*If your counter starts at 1,000, and increments by 1 every second, then after 60 seconds it would be 1,000.* <--- ???

Comment: @ScottMarcus, ha! Yeah, the math didn't add up there! Good catch! It should be 1,060.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with pure Javascript running in your users' browsers. Why does this work? Because, with extremely few exceptions, users' machines are synchronized to [global network time protocol servers](https://www.nwtime.org/). Certainly mobile phones are synchronized; Satnav / GPS depend on accurate times of day. Most desktop / laptop machines are also synchronized.

So, if you want to show all your visitors the same counter put this HTML into your page. You can do this in Gutenberg with a Custom HTML block.

```html
<script>
window.setInterval ( function tick () {
  const counter = document.getElementById('counter')
  if (counter) {
    const secondsSinceStartDate = Math.trunc(0.001 * 
        (Date.now() - Date.parse('2023-05-30T00:00:00')))
    counter.innerText = secondsSinceStartDate
  }
}, 1000)
</script>

<p>
  <span id="counter">123</span> is the count now!
</p>
```

The `<span>` displays the counter. The Javascript updates it once a second to the number of seconds since a date / time you specify.

This is the right way to do a time-based incrementing counter. It doesn't require any back-and-forth between each browser and the server.